How do I set up github personal access tokens to access a third party repository?
I have an old repository that is not owned by me, that I have access to. I haven't used it since before personal access tokens. Nor has the owner of the repository, so my access should still be there.
I'm trying to set up a personal access token to push to this repository, and not having any success. I used the PAT as the password on 'git push'
git push
Password for 'https://myuser@github.com': 
remote: Permission to blahuser/blahrepo.git denied to myusername.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/blahuser/blahrepo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

I gave the token access to all repos, and a gave it readwrite access to all permissions. What more do I need to do?
EDIT: This token works to access my repositories, just not the one I do not own, but have access to.
Edit: added git push, and password prompt to the example. Clarified that I used the PAT for the password.

Having the same issue currently, have you managed to get it to work?

Update: Managed to get it working by using the classic tokens instead of the fine grained ones. This helped me out: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/53641


First you need to set the remote url using the command

git remote set-url origin https://yourusername@github.com/user/repo.git
In your case it should be git remote set-url origin https://blahuser@github.com/blahuser/blahrepo.git 
Then you'll be asked for a password when trying to git push,

paste the personal access token you created earlier as the password


I currently have a url of https://github.com/blahuser/blahrepo.git. Does the format make a difference. Pasting in the token as the password with the current url just gets the 403.

Yea, the format makes a difference.
use the below to set the remote url
git remote set-url origin https://yourusername@github.com/blahuser/blahrepo.git 

git remote set-url origin https://myusername@github.com/theirusername/repository.git same 403. I think the only difference with your suggestion is I don't have to type the username each time. Other than that, same exact behaviour
